# How to create c++ lib with specific architecture?

Tags: c++, gradle

I am using gradle to build c++ library

[C++ library gradle reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cpp_library_plugin.html)

**1. Configure library target machines**

```
library {
    targetMachines = [
        machines.linux.x86_64,
        machines.windows.x86, machines.windows.x86_64,
        machines.macOS.x86_64
    ]
}
```

**2. Configure library linkages**

```
library {
    linkage = [Linkage.STATIC, Linkage.SHARED]
}
```

I can't understant the above targetmachines and linkage code. I want to create c++ library with specific architecture.

Can any one explain what is the purpose of those code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference you've provided gives a very good documentation of what is needed.

There are 2 types of libraries, `static` and `shared`, that you can create.
For the `linkage` config, you will have to specify the type of library that you would like to create.

The `targetMachines` specifies the configuration of the system where your library is expected to be used.

one example here could be

```
library{
targetMachines= [machines.windows.x86, machines.windows.x86_64]
linkage = [Linkage.STATIC]
}
```

Comment: I have doubt about msvcrt : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149003/msvcrtd-libexe-main-obj-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-refer